# YouTube API - $videoSnippet->setDescription() function is adds extra slash for every comma ' character

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

When I'm uploading a title or a description from my webapp through the YouTube API (PHP) its adding a trailing slash ( php escape slash ) before the character

example:

I have a text area that has the word:

here's  or let's

when submitted I'm uploading to youtube like this:
`$videoSnippet->setDescription( "$video_description" );`

but when it uploads, it shows as:

here's  or let's

How do I avoid this?

I tried stripslashes() did not help

Comment: please edit your code and include [example]

Comment: _"when submitted I'm uploading to youtube like this: 
`$videoSnippet->setDescription( "$video_description" );`"_ - and you are sure the backslashes weren't contained in what you have in `$video_description` there already ...? (Don't say Yes, unless you actually _verified_ this.) And why are you putting that variable into double quotes there to begin with?

Comment: And FYI, _trailing_ means "at the end", it has nothing to do with what "direction" that slash is leaning in ... so with "adding a trailing slash ... before the character" you are already contradicting yourself here ;-)